# Ошибка при создании функции триггера PostgreSQL: в записи "new" нет поля

Tags: postgresql, триггер

Существуют таблицы note(id_note, id_client) - Записи и  client(id_client, visit_num) - Клиент. Мне надо создать триггер, чтобы при добавлении в note, количество посещений visit_num у client увеличивалось на 1. Изначально у всех клиентов visit_num=0.

Вот мой код:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION trigger_insert_count() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE client
    SET NEW.visit_num=NEW.visit_num+1
    FROM client AS cl 
    INNER JOIN note ON cl.id_client=note.id_client;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$
LANGUAGE  plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER tg_insert_count
AFTER INSERT ON note 
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_insert_count();
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
ERROR: ОШИБКА:  в записи "new" нет поля "visit_num"
CONTEXT:  SQL-оператор: "UPDATE client
    SET NEW.visit_num=NEW.visit_num+1
    FROM client AS cl 
    INNER JOIN note ON cl.id_client=note.id_client"
функция PL/pgSQL trigger_insert_count(), строка 3, оператор SQL-оператор
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, как исправить!!!

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) пункты 5 и 3

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE note (
  id_note INT, 
  id_client INT
  );
CREATE TABLE client (
  id_client INT,
  visit_num INT
  );
INSERT INTO client VALUES (1, 0), (2,0);
```

```
CREATE FUNCTION trigger_insert_count() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE client
    SET visit_num=visit_num+1
    WHERE id_client=NEW.id_client;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$
LANGUAGE  plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER tg_insert_count
AFTER INSERT ON note 
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_insert_count();
```

```
INSERT INTO note VALUES (1,1), (2,2), (3,1);
```

```
SELECT * FROM note;
SELECT * FROM client;
```

| id_note | id_client |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

| id_client | visit_num |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OVJJVhPI)